# Error while retrieving package metadata in installation of nuget package in VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, active-directory, package, nuget, metadata

I am facing this issue while I install the nuget package. It shows error:

"Error finding repository for 'https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/curated-feeds/microsoftdotnet/': An error occurred while retrieving package metadata for 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.3.5.207081303-alpha' from source 'Microsoft and .NET'.
  A task was canceled.
Retrieving package 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory 3.5.207081303-alpha' from 'nuget.org'.
Installing NuGet package Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.3.5.207081303-alpha.
Successfully installed 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory 3.5.207081303-alpha' to CoreDemo
Executing nuget actions took 28.51 ms"

It looks like package installed successfully but it is not working fine, I guess. I want to know if the metadata is that much important for the package?

[Error while installing a nugget package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TENyP.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The metadata are stored in package.nuspec which used to log the package information, include package id, title, version, license information, description, dependencies and so on. When I try remove this content from the .nuspec file and try pack the package, it failed because the missing content. So it is import for the package.

According to the error message, your problem occurs when retrieving package metadata from the url, you need to check the package source from Tools -> Options -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Sources first. Make sure the package source is correct.

And I have install the same package in my side with Visual Studio 2015 update 3 successful, I suggest you reinstall this package again after checking the package source.